# Getting a modal-popup script to run from a linked javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a short script that opens/closes a pop-up menu in a simple MVC application.

I can't get it to work when I put the script in it's own .js file and link to it in the cshtml file.

Here's the HTML:

```
    <button id="modal">Advanced Filters</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <div class="mCheckboxes">
                <input type="checkbox" name="moreFilters" value="filter4" />Filter 4<br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="moreFilters" value="filter5" />Filter 5<br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="moreFilters" value="filter6" />Filter 6<br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("modal");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

When I just put the script at the bottom of the HTML file it works fine and clicking the button [results in the pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdO5D.png) as desired (and it closes appropriately)

However when I move the script into it's own file and add the following link at the head of the HTML file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Main.js"></script>
```

it stops working. The button just doesn't do anything. I know it's finding the file because intellisense can navigate to and select it when entering "~/ ..."

What am I missing? Does the script need to be altered in order to function when linked to in another file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the 'async' option to the link to the .js file. Otherwise the Javascript wouldn't run.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Main.js" async></script>
```